# Double SLIDER - SIGN IN/UP FORM Converting to React

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

Want to convert thin in react
https://codepen.io/FlorinPop17/pen/vPKWjd?editors=1010

Was successfully able to get HTML & Styling in but the JavaScript code
How can I convert it into React

```
 const SignInForm = () => {
    // const sceneEl = useRef(null);

    // useEffect(() => {
    //     const parallaxInstance = new Parallax(sceneEl.current, {
    //         relativeInput: true,
    //     });

    //     parallaxInstance.enable();

    //     return () => parallaxInstance.disable();
    // }, []);
    const container = () => {
        document.getElementById("container");
    };
    const signUpButton = () => {
        container.classList.add("right-panel-active");
    };
    const signInButton = () => {
        container.classList.remove("right-panel-active");
    };

    return (
        <div className="sigin">
            <div className="container" id="container">
                <div className="form-container sign-up-container">
                    <form action="#">
                        <h1>Create Account</h1>
                        <div className="social-container">
                            {/* <a href="#" className="social">
                                <i className="fab fa-facebook-f"></i>
                            </a>
                            <a href="#" className="social">
                                <i className="fab fa-google-plus-g"></i>
                            </a>
                            <a href="#" className="social">
                                <i className="fab fa-linkedin-in"></i>
                            </a> */}
                        </div>
                        <span>or use your email for registration</span>
                        <input type="text" placeholder="Name" />
                        <input type="email" placeholder="Email" />
                        <input type="password" placeholder="Password" />
                        <button
                            onClick={signUpButton }
                        >
                            Sign Up
                        </button>
                    </form>
                </div>
                <div className="form-container sign-in-container">
                    <form action="#">
                        <h1>Sign in</h1>
                        <div className="social-container">
                            {/* <a href="#" className="social">
                                <i className="fab fa-facebook-f"></i>
                            </a>
                            <a href="#" className="social">
                                <i className="fab fa-google-plus-g"></i>
                            </a>
                            <a href="#" className="social">
                                <i className="fab fa-linkedin-in"></i>
                            </a> */}
                        </div>
                        <span>or use your account</span>
                        <input type="email" placeholder="Email" />
                        <input type="password" placeholder="Password" />
                        Forgot your password?
                        {/* <a href="#">Forgot your password?</a> */}
                        <button
                            onClick={signInButton }
                        >
                            Sign In
                        </button>
                    </form>
                </div>
                <div className="overlay-container">
                    <div className="overlay">
                        <div className="overlay-panel overlay-left">
                            <h1>Welcome Back!</h1>
                            <p>
                                To keep connected with us please login with your
                                personal info
                            </p>
                            <button className="ghost" id="signIn">
                                Sign In
                            </button>
                        </div>
                        <div className="overlay-panel overlay-right">
                            <h1>Hello, Friend!</h1>
                            <p>
                                Enter your personal details and start journey
                                with us
                            </p>
                            <button className="ghost" id="signUp">
                                Sign Up
                            </button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
};

export default SignInForm;
```

And My Stlying which I have applied is as follow

```
.sigin {
  display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    height: 100%;
    padding-top: 200px;
  


* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
    background: #f6f5f7;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    flex-direction: column;
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
    height: 100vh;
    margin: -20px 0 50px;
}

h1 {
    font-weight: bold;
    margin: 0;
}

h2 {
    text-align: center;
}

p {
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: 100;
    line-height: 20px;
    letter-spacing: 0.5px;
    margin: 20px 0 30px;
}

span {
    font-size: 12px;
}

a {
    color: #333;
    font-size: 14px;
    text-decoration: none;
    margin: 15px 0;
}

button {
    border-radius: 20px;
    border: 1px solid #FF4B2B;
    background-color: #FF4B2B;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-weight: bold;
    padding: 12px 45px;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    transition: transform 80ms ease-in;
}

button:active {
    transform: scale(0.95);
}

button:focus {
    outline: none;
}

button.ghost {
    background-color: transparent;
    border-color: #FFFFFF;
}

form {
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    flex-direction: column;
    padding: 0 50px;
    height: 100%;
    text-align: center;
}

input {
    background-color: #eee;
    border: none;
    padding: 12px 15px;
    margin: 8px 0;
    width: 100%;
}

.container {
    background-color: #fff;
    border-radius: 10px;
    box-shadow: 0 14px 28px rgba(0,0,0,0.25), 
            0 10px 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.22);
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 768px;
    max-width: 100%;
    min-height: 480px;
  
}

.form-container {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    height: 100%;
    transition: all 0.6s ease-in-out;
}

.sign-in-container {
    left: 0;
    width: 50%;
    z-index: 2;
}

.container.right-panel-active .sign-in-container {
    transform: translateX(100%);
}

.sign-up-container {
    left: 0;
    width: 50%;
    opacity: 0;
    z-index: 1;
}

.container.right-panel-active .sign-up-container {
    transform: translateX(100%);
    opacity: 1;
    z-index: 5;
    animation: show 0.6s;
}

@keyframes show {
    0%, 49.99% {
        opacity: 0;
        z-index: 1;
    }
    
    50%, 100% {
        opacity: 1;
        z-index: 5;
    }
}

.overlay-container {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 50%;
    width: 50%;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    transition: transform 0.6s ease-in-out;
    z-index: 100;
}

.container.right-panel-active .overlay-container{
    transform: translateX(-100%);
}

.overlay {
    background: #FF416C;
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(to right, #FF4B2B, #FF416C);
    background: linear-gradient(to right, #FF4B2B, #FF416C);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: 0 0;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    position: relative;
    left: -100%;
    height: 100%;
    width: 200%;
    transform: translateX(0);
    transition: transform 0.6s ease-in-out;
}

.container.right-panel-active .overlay {
    transform: translateX(50%);
}

.overlay-panel {
    position: absolute;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    flex-direction: column;
    padding: 0 40px;
    text-align: center;
    top: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 50%;
    transform: translateX(0);
    transition: transform 0.6s ease-in-out;
}

.overlay-left {
    transform: translateX(-20%);
}

.container.right-panel-active .overlay-left {
    transform: translateX(0);
}

.overlay-right {
    right: 0;
    transform: translateX(0);
}

.container.right-panel-active .overlay-right {
    transform: translateX(20%);
}

.social-container {
    margin: 20px 0;
}

.social-container a {
    border: 1px solid #DDDDDD;
    border-radius: 50%;
    display: inline-flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    margin: 0 5px;
    height: 40px;
    width: 40px;
}

}

.sig-container{
    body {
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
  background: #eee;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

button {
  margin: 0;
  width: auto;
  overflow: visible;

  background: transparent;

  /* inherit font & color from ancestor */
  color: inherit;
  font: inherit;

  /* Normalize `line-height`. Cannot be changed from `normal` in Firefox 4+. */
  line-height: normal;

  /* Corrects font smoothing for webkit */
  -webkit-font-smoothing: inherit;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: inherit;

  /* Corrects inability to style clickable `input` types in iOS */
  -webkit-appearance: none;

  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;

  border: 2px solid;
  border-radius: 3em;
  padding: 0.5em 2em;
  transition: transform 80ms ease-in;
  cursor: pointer;
}

button:active {
  transform: scale(0.95);
}

input {
  background-color: #eee;
  border: none;
  padding: 12px 15px;
  margin: 8px 0;
  width: 100%;
}

a {
  color: #333;
  font-size: 14px;
  text-decoration: none;
  margin: 15px 0;
}

//  .button
//  background: ${({ theme }) => theme.color.brand};
//  border: none;
//  color: white;
//  margin: 1rem;
// }
.container{
    background-color: white;
    border-radius: 10px;
    box-shadow: 0 14px 28px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25), 0 10px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.22);
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 768px;
    max-width: 100%;
    min-height: 480px;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
    margin: 2em auto;
    align-items: center;
  
    .container__form {
      padding: 4rem;
      overflow: hidden;
    }
  
    .container__form--one {
      grid-column: 1 / span 1;
      grid-row: 1;
    }
  
    .container__form--two {
      grid-column: 2 / span 1;
      grid-row: 1;
    }
  
    .overlay {
      grid-column: 1;
      grid-row: 1;
    }
}
}
```

When I am trying to convert the file to react and connect to javascript the toggle is not working

Comment: In React you generally attach click handlers directly to the elements being rendered. We also don't directly mutate the DOM, i.e. mutating the `classList`, use the `className` prop on the `container` element. What have you tried and what isn't working? We can't help address code we can't see. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Yeah but could not made it work

Comment: @DrewReese I have updated the code Could you kindly help

Comment: Thanks for the update. Can you clarify more specifically what isn't working in your conversion? Could you try creating a *running* codesandbox demo of your React code that we could inspect and debug live?

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/laughing-parm-g2jc2s?file=/src/styles.css

@DrewReese I have Made the Code Live, actually what is happening is that the Signup & sigin Button is not working it should work something like this

https://codepen.io/FlorinPop17/pen/vPKWjd?editors=1010

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In React we don't directly mutate the DOM. It is also considered anti-pattern to query the DOM to access the DOMNodes (*document.getElementById*), use React refs instead to gain access to the underlying DOMNodes.

In this case you should use and update some React state to conditionally add the `"right-panel-active"` class to the `".container"` `div` element.

```
const SignInForm = () => {
  const [swapPanel, setSwapPanel] = useState(false);

  const signUpButton = () => {
    setSwapPanel(true);
  };
  const signInButton = () => {
    setSwapPanel(false);
  };

  return (
    <div className="sigin">
      <div
        className={["container", swapPanel ? "right-panel-active" : null]
          .filter(Boolean)
          .join(" ")}
        id="container"
      >
        <div className="form-container sign-up-container">
          <form action="#">
            <h1>Create Account</h1>
            <div className="social-container"></div>
            <span>or use your email for registration</span>
            <input type="text" placeholder="Name" />
            <input type="email" placeholder="Email" />
            <input type="password" placeholder="Password" />
            <button onClick={signUpButton}>Sign Up</button>
          </form>
        </div>
        <div className="form-container sign-in-container">
          <form action="#">
            <h1>Sign in</h1>
            <div className="social-container"></div>
            <span>or use your account</span>
            <input type="email" placeholder="Email" />
            <input type="password" placeholder="Password" />
            Forgot your password?
            {/* <a href="#">Forgot your password?</a> */}
            <button onClick={signInButton}>Sign In</button>
          </form>
        </div>
        <div className="overlay-container">
          <div className="overlay">
            <div className="overlay-panel overlay-left">
              <h1>Welcome Back!</h1>
              <p>
                To keep connected with us please login with your personal info
              </p>
              <button
                type="button"
                onClick={signInButton}
                className="ghost"
                id="signIn"
              >
                Sign In
              </button>
            </div>
            <div className="overlay-panel overlay-right">
              <h1>Hello, Friend!</h1>
              <p>Enter your personal details and start journey with us</p>
              <button
                type="button"
                onClick={signUpButton}
                className="ghost"
                id="signUp"
              >
                Sign Up
              </button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
```

It's even easier if you use the [classnames](https://www.npmjs.com/package/classnames) module. Instead of:

```
className={["container", swapPanel ? "right-panel-active" : null]
  .filter(Boolean)
  .join(" ")}
```

use

```
import classnames from 'classnames';

...

className={classnames("container", { "right-panel-active": swapPanel })}
```

[image: Edit double-slider-sign-in-up-form-converting-to-react]

Comment: className={[
                    "container",
                    swapPanel ? "right-panel-active" : null,
                ]
                    .filter(Boolean)
                    .join(" ")}
                id="container"

@Drew Reese can you explain this

Comment: @ShubhamRaj The classlist is just a space delineated string of classes. The code you ask about is just a way to conditionally include a classname in this list.